# UICollectionView cell disappearing after seconds or when taping screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm developing my first iPad app with Xcode 5.1 on iOS 7.0 and I'm using `UICollectionView`.

[Here is an sketch of my storyboard](http://imageshack.com/a/img594/8199/np1m.png)

My CollectionViewController is included into a view of my initial controller when I'm clicking of the first tab in the navigation bar.

Cells disappear after few seconds or when I'm clicking somewhere onto the screen.

If I put the CollectionViewController as initial view controller, cells are ok!

I don't understand!
Help is need, please.

```
#import "ActiviteViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Embarcation.h"
#import "CollectionActiviteCellController.h"

@interface ActiviteViewController ()

@end

@implementation ActiviteViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self; }

- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 618)]; }


-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES; }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    // Fetching Records and saving it in "fetchedRecordsArray" object
    self.embarcationsArray = [appDelegate getAllPayments];
    [self.collectionView reloadData]; }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1; }

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.embarcationsArray count]; }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     CollectionActiviteCellController *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MonEmbarcation"
forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Embarcation * embarcation = [self.embarcationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCell.labelEmbarcation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ ",embarcation.nom,embarcation.etat];

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ ",embarcation.nom,embarcation.etat]);

    return myCell; }

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a
little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller. }
*/

@end
```

Comment: Have you set your datasource correctly? You are probably doing a reloadData somewhere when the array which you use to fill the collectionCells with is empty. Also have your registered the CustomCell? Either way. Post all relevant code concerning the CollectionView

Comment: I post all the revenant code, I tried to delete reloadData but nothing change

Comment: No need to delete the reloadData :O! You just need to check the status and the data that is in your 'embarcationsArray'. Can you replace '[appDelegate getAllPayments];' with a hardcoded array as an experiment? Also I do not see you registering your cell (or mention this of any kind) so can you add this line to your viewDidLoad method? [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionActiviteCellController class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionActiviteCellController"];. Btw I'm assuming you setup your 'CollectionActiviteCellController' correctly to extend 'UICollectionViewCell'!

Comment: Also interesting to look into: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the dataSource outlet to your view controller via code or Storyboard.

Code:

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
```

Or via storyboard ctrl+drag from the collection view to the yellow rectangle representing your view controller object and than choose 'dataSource'.

[image: Outlets dragged from collection view]